# 6.0.1 fails to send MMS over PIA Always-On VPN when using 4G LTE

Tags: security, networking, 6.0-marshmallow, vpn, t-mobile

Yesterday, I set up a [PIA](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/) VPN. I've configured it to use [IPv4](http://www.pocketables.com/2014/01/android-tip-dont-use-ipv6-need-vpn-capability-t-mobile.html) over T-Mobile 4G LTE.

**I'm unable to send or receive MMS while connected to the VPN** -- they can be sent/received as normal when the VPN is disconnected. Any insight as to the origin or solution for this problem would be appreciated.

SMS works. Voice works. WiFi calling works.

- Using L2TP/IPSec PSK.
- VPN server is configured on the Android device using IP, rather than domain name.
- DNS server is also configured by IP
- I have no L2TP secret.
- No IPSec ID
- Using IPSec pre-shared key
- Not using any DNS search domains
- No forwarding routes configured

I suspect there is some sort of configuration issue with my APN settings; the current configuration works when disconnected from the VPN.

** Update - I haven't yet found a resolution to this specific issue. After getting frustrated using the manual configuration in the settings menu I decided I would try their [official Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.privateinternetaccess.android&hl=en). It will set up the connection for you. Unfortunately, the currently version of the app doesn't expose what specific configuration it is using.

[image: APN Settings page 1]
[image: APN Settings page 2]
[image: APN Settings page 3]
[image: About this phone page]

Comment: If you can send/receive MMS messages with the VPN disconnected, your APN settings are correct. Remember that MMS uses a data connection, not your normal "voice" connection like phone and SMS messages do. I can't say for certain, but this probably failing because you are not using T-Mobiles DNS servers or you are not accessing them from "inside" T-Mobiles network due to the VPN which will cause them to fail because the device is not seen as on Tmo's network.

Comment: @acejavelin Based on this, it sounds like configuring my connection to use TMO DNS is the correct option: this would seem to make sense if the MMSC can't be resolved. Will troubleshoot more later today and post updates...

Comment: It is just a guess, that is why I left it as a comment and not an answer, but it seems reasonable knowing that the APN is correct since it works when the VPN is disabled.

Answer (score 3):

I've just found an [issue in AOSP](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196912) that tracks this and has a suggested fix for it:

> I tried Textra as a texting replacement app (for other reasons). In
>   the settings it has an option to use either System or Legacy protocols
>   for MMS. It even tells the user to try System if they have a VPN
>   enabled. I switched to System from the default Legacy, and now my MMS
>   works flawlessly with a VPN running.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this @zamber -- I tried out Textra and it unfortunately didn't work for me. It appears to have worked for others in some instances, however. There seems to be a great many issues open against Android's Always-On VPN as evidenced by a site-specific search https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3Acode.google.com+%22Always-on+vpn%22

Comment: Doing site specific searches will do you no good as you'll get closed issues too. It looks like there are 25 open issues that match "always on vpn" https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=always+on+vpn&colspec=ID+Status+Priority+Owner+Summary+Stars+Reporter+Opened&cells=tiles . Take a look through these issues (and the old ones too) to see how you could debug your issue.